# Date range backgroundElement shading on datetimeaxis

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

How would I go about shading a date range in my flex chart using backgroundelements? For example, if I have a start date and an end date, how do I pass these date objects so that range can be shaded on my chart? I've seen the localToData() method but that seems to need to know your mouse postion. I would like on runtime to pass my date objects and have the chart take those dates and figure out the points on the chart for the range. Is datatolocal the way to go? And if so how? Please help!

Thanks,
tone